# Angular Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal <- Controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

After upgrading to angular-bootstrap 1.2, this error occurred when loading my app:

`Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal <- Controller`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Angular UI Bootstrap renamed the `$modal` directive to `$uibModal` in **version 0.14.0**.

Also note that `$modalInstance` is now `$uibModalInstance`.

See the Angular UI Bootstrap [documentation for Modal here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

Comment: (Just wasted an hour trying to get around this problem... I didn't realise they'd renamed it...   I need a beer..)

Comment: I also need a beer! Thanks for the fix here though :)